# How to register a Handlebars partial outside partials folder on Sails.js?

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, sails.js

I have the following folder structure on my Sails.js application:

`assets/
   myModule/
 views/
   partials/`

Where `myModule` is a Backbone component (although my client is *not* a full Backbone application)

There's a given Handlebar partial `x.handlebars` that need to be rendered both via server and client sides.

My struggle starts when `views/` is **not accessible** on client side so there's no way to load it on Backbone module.

Then I have tried to move it to `assets/myModule/templates/` which would be accessible but now my main template `views/layout.handlebars` can't load that partial if I try something like:

`{{> ../assets/myModule/templates/x}}`

which doesn't work as well (I assume Handlebars use views/ as root level for the layouts).

There's only two possible solutions I'm seeing in that situation:

- Duplicate these layouts and use one on each location (not ideal, but works)
- Place it on `assets/myModules/templates/x` and register a Handlebars partial on Sails to let it available for the server-side rendering.

How could I do that second solution? Is that possible to register a global partial the same way we can do it with the helpers function under `config/views.js`?

My goal is to use `Handlebars.registerPartial` function on config level, **outside** a Controller so that partial could be reused by other templates as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duplicating the code is not necessary. There are many different ways you can implement this and depends on the optimization profile you will be looking for.

A simple solution would be to read the hbs file in the api/controller with node's fs, then compile it with Handlebars and pass it to the template like this:

```
var rawTemplate = fs.readFileSync('assets/hbs/client-side-template.hbs', "utf8");
var processedTemplate = Handlebars.compile(rawTemplate);

return res.render('whiteboard/dualloadview', {      
  myPartialAsVariable: processedTemplate({})
});
```

You'll have have to figure out how to handle the context and variables used by the partials. You can also improve on this code snippet to by looking into keeping the file read in memory, and looking into how to register partials with Handlebars instead of using a variable.